# AJAX getting called, even though doc is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have this chunk of code in my coffeescript:

```
$('.asdasd').ready ->
  $.ajax '/splunk/100000000',
  type: 'GET'
  cache: false
  success: (html) ->
    $('.splunk_results').append html
```

The `asdasd` div doesn't even exist -- however, in my console, I can see a call to /splunk/10000000" being made. Why is this happening?

EDIT:

I think the issue might have to do with the fact that the div in question isn't loaded with the initial page -- the page is full of partials, and the div is only loaded with the click on another js button that modifies the DOM. I basically want to see when that div exists, and when it does, make a new request and populate the div with the results of that request.

Comment: is this code wrapped in a [`DOMReady`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()) event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(heavily edited in response to question edit)

`.ready` is only a valid event for document.  [jQuery's documentation for `ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) doesn't define behavior for cases where the argument to `$` isn't `document`. That said, there's nothing stopping you from defining an event that acts the way you want!  Rather than listening for the ready event, invent a custom event (say, `readyForSplunk`) and trigger it at the appropriate time.

The document, or some nearer parent of the to-be-created `asdasd` div, should have a delegate handler listening for the `readyForSplunk` event.  The js button that creates the `asdasd` div should also [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)`('readyForSplunk')` the new div.

Comment: That's a good point. I added an edit to specify my problem further

Answer (score 1):

`ready` runs when the [DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). If you only would like it to run if the element in question is in the page, you could do something like this instead:

```
_get = ->
  $.ajax '/splunk/100000000',
    type: 'GET'
    cache: false
    success: (html) ->
      $('.splunk_results').append html

$('.asdasd').each ->
  _get()
  _get = ->
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, it might have to do with the edit I made above